# Hiding list items without losing order

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to hide certain `<li>` of an `<ol>` without changing the numbers in front of each list item? I'm trying to make a search function which only shows the `<li>` which match the input of the user. However if for example the second `<li>` was to be hidden it would change number in front of the third `<li>` to a 2, but it should remain a 3.

If possible, I'm looking for an answer without the use of jQuery (Prototype is fine though). But if it can't be done without jQuery then it is acceptable to use jQuery.

HTML:

```
<label>Search: <input type="text" id="search"/></label> 
<button id="clear">Clear</button>

<div id="list">
    <ol>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("search").onkeyup = updateList;
    document.getElementById("clear").click = clearInput;
}

function updateList(){
    var list = document.getElementById("list");
    var listitems = list.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
        var current = listitems[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase();
        if(current.indexOf(document.getElementById("search").value.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            listitems[i].style.display = "list-item";
        } else {
            listitems[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }   
}

function clearInput(){
    document.getElementById("search").value = "";
    updateList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/CYs46/

**visibility** + **height** ;-)

A little change from your code as fiddle

```
    if(current.indexOf(document.getElementById("search").value.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
        listitems[i].style.visibility = "visible";
        listitems[i].style.height = "auto";
    } else {
        listitems[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
        listitems[i].style.height = "0px";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change a class name of the items if I wanted to hide it and make the items visually disappear without use of `display: none`:

```
var value = document.getElementById("search").value.toLowerCase();
if (value && current.indexOf(value) != -1) {
    listitems[i].className = "hidden";
} else {
    listitems[i].className = "";
}
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000px;
    left: -1000px;
}
```

Also I fixed you code a little: you need to check that search terms is not empty before you show/hide items.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/43PcY/2/

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However checking for a value is not needed in this case. If the user either completely removes the input or click on the Clear button, it should also update the list.

Answer (score 0):

Set visibility to hidden, and height to zero (only height might also work):

```
document.getElementById('hideme').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('hideme').style.height = '0px';
document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('hideme').style.visibility = '';
    document.getElementById('hideme').style.height = '';
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZd5E/1/)

Edit: Without jQuery